# Cannot Access js-cookie in a Vue component with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-mix

I want to use the NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie in my application to manage cookies in Vue.js components

I have installed it using:

```
npm i js-cookie
```

In my app.js I have added...

```
require('js-cookie');
```

But when I try to use in a Vue.js component like this...

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```

I get...

> "ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined"

I feel like I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is simple.

```
require('js-cookie');
```

should be

```
const Cookies = require('js-cookie');
```

[The library is smart enough to understand a module bundler is available and export itself as a module](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js#L15), but you need to specify what you want to assign that export to in your requiring code.

Comment: That didnt work, but window.Cookies = require('js-cookies'); does